# jQuery DOM related issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I am facing a kind of strange issue with my jQuery DOM;
My code is as follows;

```
$("#"+iframeId).attr("src",url);
$("a[target="+iframeId+"]").attr("href", url);
```

Here iframeId gets the value "swcontent"

Now the 1st statement works fine, but the 2nd statement does not return anything, even though I have a link on my page as;

```
<a target="swcontent" href="xyz.html" class="standardMenu_on">Link</a>
```

Now the strange part is in my Firebug inspector, if I write

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute("target")
```

it does find the target "swcontent"

Could you please let me know why this might be the case..

Comment: Just to add if I add a reference to jquery.js in my JSP, it seems to work fine....But for some reasons, I want to avoid it, as there are already many other jquery based things within my jsp like jquery-ui.js , jquery.dimensions, thickbox, etc

Comment: Not sure if the issue is with jQuery definition. But if that is the case, not sure how does the 1st statement ($("#"+iframeId).attr("src",url); ) work fine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var url = "http://www.yahoo.com";
$("a[target=swcontent]").attr("href", url);
alert(document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].outerHTML);
```

This works for me.

Comment: Just to add if I add a reference to jquery.js in my JSP, it seems to work fine....But for some reasons, I want to avoid it, as there are already many other jquery based things within my jsp like jquery-ui.js , jquery.dimensions, thickbox, etc

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is wrap your jQuery in the document ready handler like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //put your jQuery in here
});
```

Tell me if that works

Comment: Actually I already have that inside $(document).ready(function(){ ..}

Comment: I do setTimeouts in my chrome extension. If (!document.getElementById('asdf')) then try again in 50 milliseconds; else proceed with our normal task. Granted your normal task is dependent upon 'asdf' being available.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enclose attribute value in quotes, see here for a working example http://jsfiddle.net/99Gua/

```
$('a[target="'+iframeId+'"]').attr("href", url);
```

Comment: Just to add if I add a reference to jquery.js in my JSP, it seems to work fine....But for some reasons, I want to avoid it.....Not sure if the issue is with jQuery definition, how does the 1st statement work fine ?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking:

```
$('a[target="'+iframeId+'"]').length
```

in firebug/console. If it's not 1, you might not be selecting what's intended.
If it's > 1, your intended selection may not be the first element it finds. It may be an a tag without an href attr.

Comment: Well...that returns 0...But as I said, there is a link element with that target (<a target="swcontent" href="xyz.html" class="standardMenu_on">Link</a> )....Also if I just add a <script> ref to jQuery, it finds that...I am looking to avoid adding that..

Answer (score 0):

Are all your script tags closed properly?
Sometimes the observation "it works if I add another script" hints at the use of empty script tags (`<script />` instead of `<script></script>`).